# Xamarin use TitleBar and TabbedPage Bar

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a question. I created a custom TitleBar like this:

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
        <Image Source="Title_Dark.png" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="25" Margin="0, 0, 20, 0" />

        <Image Source="Add.png" HorizontalOptions="End" HeightRequest="35" Margin="0, 0, 8, 0">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="imgAdd_Clicked" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
    </StackLayout>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

And when I click on the image "Add" in the TitleBar, I go to a TabbedPage like this:

```
TabbedPage page = new TabbedPage();
page.Children.Add(new MemeBuilder());
page.Children.Add(new MemeTemplateList());

await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
```

Now I want to keep the TitleBar from the firstpage and use the tabbedpage bar below that bar. Is this possible and how?

Comment: No, when you push to a new page, the navigationbar is a new one of the new page. You can create the same TitleView in the new page so it will look the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the use of `ControlTemplate`

Define `ControlTemplate` in **App.xaml**

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TopBar">
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
        <Image Source="Title_Dark.png" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="25" Margin="0, 0, 20, 0" />

        <Image Source="Add.png" HorizontalOptions="End" HeightRequest="35" Margin="0, 0, 8, 0">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{TemplateBinding Parent.BindinContext.Command1}" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
    </StackLayout>
</ControlTemplate>
```

On any `ContentPage` that use Shell

```cs
Shell.TitleView = new TemplatedView(Application.Current.Resources["TopBar"]);
```

```xml
<ContentPage>
<Shell.TitleView>
<TemplatedView ControlTemplate={StaticResource TopBar} />
</Shell.TitleView>
</ContentPage>
```

On ContentPages which are using default NavigationPage

```xml
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
<TemplatedView ControlTemplate={StaticResource TopBar}/>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```