# How to remove upper header content with xamarian forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i am new to xamarian app development. now this is my markup code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SmartEntry.DashBoard"
             BackgroundColor="White"
             Title="DASHBOARD"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Icon="logout_icon.png" Order="Primary" Priority="1" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

and this is my view on android emulator :

[image]

**---------------------------updated-----------------------------**

[image]

Comment: Is `HasNavigationBar=false` what you want?

Comment: if i set NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" then Title got disappears.

Comment: ok, the picture confused me. One approach is to use a [ControlTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59275639/199364).

Comment: or make a [custom TitleVIew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62464021/199364).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve the picture is clear toppest <- and logout icon remove. only to view <- DASHBOARD  with Logout icon to show.

Comment: **Please read** the answers at the two links I gave. **Google for docs or further examples** about those two techniques.. **Attempt to write code** that does what you want. **If you get it working,** then you could add "Your Answer" below, so everyone benefits from what you learned. OR **If you encounter a problem,** then Add that new code to your question. Explain what happens given that new code, and how that differs from your goal.

Answer (score 1):

> How to remove upper header content with xamarian forms

If you want to remove the upper header content(the back button),you can set

```
NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
```

In this condition, the `Title`(`DASHBOARD`) will move to the left.

If you  want to remove the back button and make the `Title`(`DASHBOARD`) display in the middle , then you can use `Title View` to achieve this.

Please refer to the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FormApp118.TestPage2"
              Title="DASHBOARD"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
             >

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label  Text="DASHBOARD"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"   VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="White"  FontSize="20"  />
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems >
        <ToolbarItem Icon="cherry.png" Order="Primary" Priority="1" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

  <!-- other code-->

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: but there is another icon with back button redrawed. see update...

Comment: I am confused with your screenshot, it seems there are two titleViews in your page. Could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?